# HaProxy number of connections limit not working

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to implement a connection limit per IP on HaProxy, but I'm still able to connect more than the limit implemented.

Here's my configuration:

```
frontend smtpv4
    bind :25

    # Table definition
    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 60s store conn_cur

    # Shut the new connection as long as the client has already 5 opened 
    tcp-request connection track-sc0 src
    acl connabuse sc0_conn_cur gt 5
    tcp-request connection reject if connabuse

    #tcp-request connection reject if { src_conn_cur gt 5 }
    #tcp-request connection track-sc0 src

    # Reject any client that speak before the aloha
    tcp-request inspect-delay 1s
    acl content_present req_len gt 0
    tcp-request content reject if content_present

    default_backend smtp_backend
```

I tried to filter via ACL (connabuse) or via condition using the quantity. I also tried using sc0, sc1, or various alternatives. But every time, I'm able to connect more than 5 simultaneous times (I was able to open 8 connections).

Also, on a side note, how can I filter both IP v4 and v6 ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I verified your config and tried to reproduce this. I could only open 5 simultaneous connections and the sixth would get refused, as I think you intended.

If you want to do the same with IPv6, set the "type" of your stick-table to "ipv6" instead of "ip".

Comment: The issue came from a global configuration parameter, identified here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1061702/haproxy-stick-table-along-with-nbproc-higher-than-1 . I'll close this conversation as it's irrelevant now (I forgot about it).