# HaProxy stick-table along with nbproc higher than 1

Tags: haproxy

I have configured a rule based on the number of IP connections using stick-table with HaProxy such as the following:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    maxconn 60000

backend connectionstablev4
   stick-table type ip size 1m expire 60s store conn_cur

frontend smtpv4
    bind :25

    tcp-request connection track-sc0 src table connectionstablev4
    acl connabuse sc_conn_cur(0,connectionstablev4) gt 5
    
   tcp-request connection reject if connabuse

    # Reject any client that speak before the aloha
    tcp-request inspect-delay 1s
    acl content_present req_len gt 0
    tcp-request content reject if content_present

    default_backend smtp_backend

backend smtp_backend
    mode tcp
    timeout server 1m
    timeout connect 5s

    # Health check
    option smtpchk HELO mx1.improvmx.com

    server srv1 127.0.0.1:2525 check send-proxy maxconn 500
```

And it works great.

But as soon as I add more processes, like this (in the global section) :

```
global
    # ... same as above

    nbproc  6
    cpu-map  1 1
    cpu-map  2 2
    cpu-map  3 3
    cpu-map  4 4
    cpu-map  5 5
    cpu-map  6 6
```

**The max connections per IP stops working.**

I suspect that the stick-table are per-process basis instead of globally, but I couldn't find any information on that matter.

The issue is clearly with the nbproc/cpu-map because as soon as I remove just this part, everything else works fine.

Is there some rule or configuration to set to indicates HaProxy to use the same stick-table for all the processes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use threads instead of processes. Your problems with processes are mentioned right in the documentation.

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#3.1-nbthread

> This setting is only available when support for threads was built in.
> It makes haproxy run on  threads. This is exclusive with
> "nbproc". While "nbproc" historically used to be the only way to use
> multiple processors, it also involved a number of shortcomings related
> to the lack of synchronization between processes (health-checks,
> peers, stick-tables, stats, ...) which do not affect threads. As such,
> any modern configuration is strongly encouraged to migrate away from
> "nbproc" to "nbthread". "nbthread" also works when HAProxy is started
> in foreground. On some platforms supporting CPU affinity, when nbproc
> is not used, the default "nbthread" value is automatically set to the
> number of CPUs the process is bound to upon startup. This means that
> the thread count can easily be adjusted from the calling process using
> commands like "taskset" or "cpuset". Otherwise, this value defaults to 1.
> The default value is reported in the output of "haproxy -vv". See also "nbproc".

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I followed some article I found online, which mentioned nbproc (probably an old one) ... that's where my troubles begun. Do you know which command I can run to know how many haproxy threads are currently running?

Comment: (or at least a way to know that, without configuration settings, haproxy is using multi threading out of the box, or if I have to configure it). `haproxy -vv` shows "Built with multi-threading support."

Comment: to see running threads you can check `stats` page (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#stats%20enable). it show it like this: `
pid = 7125 (process #1, nbproc = 1, nbthread = 2)` somewhere on top. also via CLI, e.g.: `echo 'show info' | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio`  will show line `Nbthread: 2` among others